# PHP regex for math operations

Tags: php, regex

So i'm trying to create a regex without success.

This is what i get as in input string:

```
String A: "##(ABC 50a- {+} UDF 69,22g,-) {*} 3##"
String B: "##ABC 0,10,- DEF {/} 9 ABC {*} UHG 3-##"
```

And this is what i need processed out of the regex:

```
Result A: "(50+69,22)*3"
String B: "0,10/9*3"
```

I just can't get the number replacement combined with the operation symbols.

This is what i got:

```
'/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\(\)\.]/'
```

Thankful for every help.

Comment: How come you have a string with extra data like `ABC, UDF`?

Comment: well it can really contain everything. only sure thing is that operations are inside {}

Comment: Strings can be more complex? (i.e. more parenthesis groups?)

Comment: A good start would be to write down in words the patterns that you want to match. For instance, you've said that you know the operations are inside `{}`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in your first attempt at a regex. Don't forget that `{` and `}` have special meanings in regexes, so need to be escaped as `\{` and `\}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple solution consists of getting rid of everything you don't want.

So replace this:

```
\{(.+?)\}|[^0-9,{}()]+|(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)
```

With `$1`.

Simple enough:

```
$input = "(ABC 50a- {+} UDF 69,22g,-) {*} 3";
$output = preg_replace('#\{(.+?)\}|[^0-9,{}()]+|(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)#', '$1', $input);
```

- `\{(.+?)\}` part matches everything inside `{`...`}` and outputs it (it gets replaced by `$1`)
- `[^0-9,{}()]+` gets rid of every character not belonging to the ones we're trying to keep (it's replaced with an empty string)
- `(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)` throws out commas which are not part of a number

Unfortunately, I can't say much else without a better spec.

Comment: This works for the samples given. I would be concerned that it might let through unexpected inputs in future, though, if they contained unexpected commas, parentheses, or braces.

Comment: @IMSoP that's exactly why I said a better spec is needed. OP says *"it can really contain everything"*, which doesn't help that much. You can't really build a lexer with the info that was given.

Comment: I absolutely agree, just wanted readers to be aware of the danger of a "blacklist" based approach like this.

Comment: well everything was a bit broad. i mean it shurly contains numbers and decimals and math operations in curly brackets. other than that everything can be expected. but thanks so far, will test it!

Comment: I also added double crosses which are to be found before and after an expression inside a text.

Comment: @Mike then first you should extract everything that matches `##(.*?)##` and process *that*.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes, i will try to apply your regex on the single matches.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ok tried your regex and it looks good, but the comma doesn't get stipped away althoug its in your expression?

Comment: @Mike no since it's in a *negated* character class.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes but here "69,22g,-" the last two chars should get stripped away. I updated the examples.

Comment: @Mike I've updated the answer to account for this case

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be to write down in words the patterns that you want to match. For instance, you've said that you know the operations are inside `{}`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in your first attempt at a regex.

You can also break it down into separate sections, and then build it up later. So for instance you might say:

- if you see parentheses, keep them in the final answer
- a number is made up either of digits...
- ...or digits followed by a comma and more digits
- an operation is always in curly braces, and is either `+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`
- everything else should be thrown away

Given the above list:

- matching parentheses is easy: `[()]`
- matching a digit can be done with `[0-9]` or `\d`; at least one is `+`; so "digits" is `\d+`
- comma digits is easy: `,\d+`; make it optional with `?`and you get `\d+(,\d+)?`
- any of four operations is just `[+*/-]`; escape the `/` and `-` to get `[+*\/\-]` don't forget that `{` and `}` have special meanings in regexes, so need to be escaped as `\{` and `\}`; our list of operations in braces becomes: `\{[+*\/\-]\}`

Now we have to put it together; one way would be to use `preg_match_all` to find all occurences of any of those patterns, in order, and then we can stick them back together. So our regex is just "this or this or this or this":

```
/[()]|\d+(,\d+)?|\{[+*\/\-]\}/
```

I haven't tested this, but given the explanation of how I arrived at it, hopefully you can figure out how to test parts of it and tweak it if necessary.

Comment: It works but capture also curly brackets. You can change it in: `/[()]|\d(,\d)?|(?<={)[+*\/\-](?=})/`

Comment: @fusion3k Ah, yes, forgot the need to match but discard the braces. Was trying to avoid advanced features like zero-width lookarounds; could maybe grab everything else into capture groups. I guess the simplest cheat would be to just remove `{` and `}` after running the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I`m not good at regex but I found another approach:

Do **EXTRA** check of input before running **eval**!!!

```
$string = "(ABC 50a- {+} UDF 69,22g) {*} 3";
$new ='';
$string = str_split($string);
foreach($string as $char) {
   if(!ctype_alnum($char) || ctype_digit($char) ){
    //you don't want letters, except symbols like {, ( etc
     $new .=$char;
   }
}
//echo $new; will output -> ( 50- {+}  69,22) {*} 3
//remove the brackets although you could put it in the if statement ...
$new = str_replace(array('{','}'),array('',''), $new);
//floating point numbers use dot not comma
$new = str_replace(',','.', $new);
$p = eval('return '.$new.';');
print $p; // -57.66
```

Used: [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php), [ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.ctype-alnum.php), [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

P.S: I assumed that the minus before the base operation is taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick try before leaving the office ;-)

```
$data = array(
  "(ABC 50a- {+} UDF 69,22g) {*} 3",
  "ABC 0,10- DEF {/} 9 ABC {*} UHG 3-"
);

foreach($data as $d) {
  echo $d . " = " . extractFormula($d) . "\n";
}

function extractFormula($string) {
  $regex = '/([()])|([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?)|\{([+\*\/-])\}/';
  preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

  $formula = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
  $formula = str_replace(array('{', '}'),NULL,$formula);
  return $formula;
}
```

Output:

```
(ABC 50a- {+} UDF 69,22g) {*} 3 = ( 50 + 69,22 ) * 3
ABC 0,10- DEF {/} 9 ABC {*} UHG 3- = 0,10 / 9 * 3
```

If some one likes to fiddle around with the code, here is a live example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/373d76a9c0948314c1d164a555bed847f1a1ed0d